# JOSM data to be exported and used in GIS

Tags: shapefile, export, josm

I need to use open street map data, specifically the turning lanes's data. I can very easily import it in JOSM but it would be useful for me if I had it o GIS format.

I am not very familiar with JOSM but it seems that I can't find a 'to export' turning lanes data, or another data from JOSM.

Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Which GIS software are you using?

Comment: Both ArcGIS and QGIS. What I do needs both for several reasons

Comment: Qgis has direct OSM importing capabilities

Comment: Yes, I know that but the information that I am looking for is not appeared on GIS. I can only view it on JOSM. What I am looking for is Boston's turning lanes, which is a recent addition to OSM.